# Functions to return Db values in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to write three functions:

1. that gets  list of all database
2. gets the table name for the database name I  provide from 1
3. gets the column name from the table name I provide from 2

I can get the  table  name of specific database I  want by writing a query to that database and getting  table names and column names. I'm looking for a way to achieve this  by specifying the parameters which a user can get values from any database and any table and column names. In short I want   my function to do act like a function which when  given the appropriate dbname, tablename and column name would work.

Comment: But [C# == Db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic)...

Comment: So have you tried anything? Post the code you have so far and we'll help you fix/improve it.